# How to fetch same plate_number from data base which appear multiple times

Tags: php, sql

I need a select query: how to fetch same plate_number from database which appear multiple times

- Database: `numbers`
- Table: `number_plate`

Sample data:

```
plate_code  plate_number
------------------------
A           45990
B           54667
c           45990
D           0908
E           54667
F           65534
G           3422
H           32009
I           0908
```

I wanted the out put to look like this :

```
A   45990
A   45990
B   54667
E   54667
I   0908
```

Comment: i wanted show out put as:
A 45990
A 45990
B 54667
E 54667
D 0908
I 0908

Comment: coloumn1 has A B C D E F G H and coloumn2 has 45990 54667 45990 0908 54667 65534 3422 32009 0908

Comment: yeah mudassar.......how we can pull matched numers

Comment: i wanted show out put as:
A 45990
A 45990
B 54667
E 54667
D 0908
I 0908

Comment: order is doesnt matter......

Comment: hasif try my answer it is very easy

Comment: myanswer doesn't work for you Hasif

Comment: nope my mudassar'

Comment: Do you get what you want ..if not then try my answer i.a you will get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very easy try this

```
   SELECT plate_code, plate_number
   FROM table_name
   WHERE plate_number  IN (
   SELECT plate_number
   FROM table_name
   GROUP BY plate_number
    HAVING COUNT(id) > 1 
    ORDER BY plate_number ASC
     ) ORDER BY plate_number ASC
```

Comment: i wanted show out put as:
A 45990
c 45990
B 54667
E 54667
D 0908
I 0908

Comment: if multiple plate_number will be their in column we should pull that

Comment: its giving all the data order by plate_code AAAAAABBBBBCCDDD like this

Comment: you want only one plate number no repetition

Comment: try now i am sure you will get what you want

Comment: hasif you don't want repetion of ABCD or numbers ..I am not clear about your out put

Comment: em concern about multiple plate_number......if plate number mulitple times  only i need to fetch that ....plate_code doesnt matter  i want output:
45990
45990
54667
54667
0908
0908

Comment: @hasif try this..think tyou will get what you want

Comment: plate_code
plate_number

M 43344 
M 95995 
O 43344 
R 10333 
R 95995 
S 10333 
M 99970 
R 9809 
R 99970 
S 9809 
S 99970 
is their any possibility to make a order ex:A 33345 C33345  D 3323 H 3323

Comment: we cannot make group of multiple occurrence of plate_number?

Comment: we are on the way i think:  it gives me this result:plate_code
plate_number   1

M 43344 
M 95995 
O 43344 
R 10333 
R 95995 
S 10333 
M 99970 
R 9809 
R 99970 
S 9809 
S 99970

Comment: it should show like this:M 43344 
O 43344 
M 95995 
R 95995 
R 10333 
S 10333

Comment: if u try one more time really helpful for me bro

Comment: the query is correct try refreshing page clear the cache and then try

Comment: wow superb dear.... ua really genius in mysql query .....thanks a lot it really great effort from you.......:-)

Comment: sorry bro i tried but its showing my reputation is less than 15...........

Comment: sure :-) bye tc

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.`count(plate_number)` with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` statements .

```
$query = "SELECT plate_code,plate_number from table_name  GROUP BY plate_number HAVING count(plate_number)>1";
```

Comment: Hi Hek mat,  I have used your query its showing #1054 - Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause'

Comment: Are you using MYSQL or any other DBMS?

Comment: try once `SELECT plate_code,plate_number from table_name WHERE count(plate_number)>1 GROUP BY plate_number`

Comment: SELECT plate_code,plate_number from number_plate WHERE count(plate_number)>1 GROUP BY plate_number
 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: I need a select query:

How to fetch same plate_number which apeear multiple times 

database:numbers

table name:number_plate

Coulumn1    column2
plate_code  plate_number
A           45990
B           54667
c           45990
D           0908
E           54667
F           65534
G           3422
H           32009
I           0908


I wanted show out put as:

A 45990
C 45990
B 54667
E 54667
D 0908
I 0908